# Missing roles in run list, Chef kitchen chef_solo

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, test-kitchen

When running kitchen converge I get the follow error:

```
================================================================================  
Error expanding the run_list:
================================================================================  
Missing Role(s) in Run List:
```

What do I need to do so that the test kitchen run can find the role?
I'm running from the chef-repo/ directory that contains the roles/ directory.

`kitchen.yml` file contents

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  roles_path: ./roles

platforms:
  - name: centos-7.1

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list: role['role-name']
    attributes:
```

Comment: The role is in ./roles and is a role-name.rb ruby file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the roles path on the provisioner to use roles with Kitchen, and this is generally not recommended as it is kind of against the point.

Comment: sorry, didn't see your reply

Comment: would you kindly elaborate a little bit about why it's against the point?

Comment: Test Kitchen is a cookbook testing tool, it works best when testing single cookbooks in isolation. Testing a role is harder because it relies on Chef's version solution to know what actual cookbooks will be used in the end so you can't test as usefully.

Comment: Where can I find the correct syntax to add the roles path on the provisioner?
I looked at the chef docs, google, and the kitchenci site, but I couldn't find it.

I guess'd it might be this:
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  roles_path: roles/
and tried that.

The roles/ with the rolename.rb files is indeed right there where the .kitchen.yml file is.  Still the same error though when running kitchen test, "Missing Roles in the Run List"

Comment: That is indeed the value, see https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/master/lib/kitchen/provisioner/chef_base.rb#L71-L74 for the relevant code.

Comment: For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586096/can-we-add-a-role-in-kitchen-yml
Under provisioner, add role_path: /path/to/roles